# How to find the biggest possible combination of two numbers under a certain threshold from a list?

Tags: python, math, optimization, mathematical-optimization, integer-arithmetic

So let's say if the list is [2,5,14,18,44], what I want to find out is what the biggest sum of two numbers under 60 would be. So the correct answer should be (14,44)

Right now I am calculating every possible combination before getting the result. It is horribly inefficient

Edit:
Here is my code. It serves to solve the problem but it is slow because the list is really long

```
    import itertools

    #build_list is a long list of all constructions with the construction cost

    #build_power1 is the available amount of funds

    #in the first line I exclude all the constructions beyond total funds

    build_list = [ i for i in self.list_of_constructions if i['cost']<build_power1]

    iter_all_build_combos = itertools.combinations(build_list,2)
    
    list_all_build_combos_with_cost = []        
    for combo in iter_all_build_combos:
        sum1 = combo[0]['cost'] + combo[1]['cost']
        list_all_build_combos_with_cost.append((sum1, combo))
    #here I have a list with all combonations alongside with the sum of the costs
    list_all_build_combos_with_cost.sort()
```

Comment: Why not 18,44? You just need to find the highest two values under your threshold no?

Comment: How large is your list? What type and range are the numbers? Is there a time limit?

Comment: Please include your solution.

Comment: By "two numbers under 60", you mean two numbers whose sum is less than 60?

Comment: Is the list already sorted?

Comment: Is it guaranteed that there *is* a valid combination? What shall be done if not?

Comment: Yes, there is such a large range that a valid combination is guaranteed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one possible approach based on iterating from both ends of the (sorted) list:

```
def best_pair(nums: list[int], threshold: int) -> tuple[int, int]:
    """Return the pair of nums whose sum is closest to threshold
    without meeting or exceeding it."""
    nums = sorted(nums)
    best = nums[0], nums[1]
    if sum(best) >= threshold:
        raise ValueError(f'No pair exists under {threshold}.')
    j = len(nums) - 1
    for i in range(len(nums) - 1):
        while nums[i] + nums[j] >= threshold:
            j -= 1
        if j <= i:
            break
        if nums[i] + nums[j] > sum(best):
            best = nums[i], nums[j]
    return best

assert best_pair([2, 4, 14, 18, 44], 60) == (14, 44)
```

For any given number in the list, there is a particular other number that forms the best possible pair.  If you iterate through the list in order from smallest to largest (`i`), the best pairing for those numbers (`j`) will always decrease.  As `i` increases, all you need to do is incrementally decrease `j` enough to keep it from "busting" the pair it forms with that `i`.  Once `j <= i` you can't form any more valid pairs, and you're done.

This drastically cuts down on the number of possibilities that you need to consider; since each iteration only goes in one direction through the list, the whole thing ends up being O(n).

Note that calling `sorted()` is O(n log n) only if the list isn't already sorted; for an already-sorted list it's O(n).  If you know for certain that the list will *always* be sorted, you can save some time by skipping it, but it doesn't change the big-O runtime.

Comment: Thanks so much for the great answer and the detailed explanation of the logic behind it!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the list is sorted as given in the example provided you can use a two-pointer approach from either side of the list for a more efficient `O(n)` solution than the `O(n^2)` you currently have:

```
from typing import Optional


def find_biggest_combination(numbers: list[int],
                             threshold: int) -> Optional[tuple[int, int]]:
    """
    Finds the biggest combination of two numbers under a certain threshold
    from a sorted list of numbers.
    
    Args:
        numbers: A sorted list of integers to search for a combination.
        threshold: An integer representing the upper limit for the sum of 
                   the combination.
        
    Returns:
        A tuple of two integers representing the biggest combination found 
        whose sum is less than the threshold, or None if no such combination
        exists.
    """
    left, right = 0, len(numbers) - 1
    biggest_combination: Optional[tuple[int, int]] = None
    while left < right:
        current_sum = numbers[left] + numbers[right]
        if current_sum >= threshold:
            right -= 1
        else:
            if not biggest_combination or current_sum > sum(biggest_combination):
                biggest_combination = (numbers[left], numbers[right])
            left += 1
    return biggest_combination


print(f'{find_biggest_combination([2, 5, 14, 18, 44], 60) = }')
```

**Output:**

```
find_biggest_combination([2, 5, 14, 18, 44], 60) = (14, 44)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This solution is definitely much faster